# Why is this Asp.Net program signing into SQL as the current user?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, connection-string

A client of mine is using some older software I had written on a newer server setup.   Despite having a *connectionstring* declared in the *web.config* file, the program keeps trying to log in as the current user and dumping out the error:

> Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\currentUserJimbo'

Any ideas what would be causing this?

Their setup

- Windows Server 2008
- IIS 7
- MSSQL 2005

Comment: Does your connection string use integrated authentication or sql authentication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have integrated authentication in the connection string and have enabled impersonation you should see that behaviour.

Integrated authentication will cause the web site to log on to the SQL server using the thread's current principal. When enabling impersonation, the thread will take the identity of the client. This can be useful if the web server is to access files or other resources on behalf of the user.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe SQL Server authentication is turned off? And it connects using Windows Authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the connection string being used doesn't have `Integrated Security=SSPI;` in it.

Check out [these connection strings](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005) for some tips.